# Using jQuery to select/deselect radio buttons with different names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have a Quiz that uses ids of the answers in the DB as the name in order to check if they're correct.  So basically I can't make them all the same name.

Anyways this leaves me with radio buttons that can be all checked and that isn't how it should work.  I found jQuery that allows for the radio buttons to be unchecked but I need them to uncheck when you click other buttons.

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <input type="radio" name="21">
    <label for="21">Answer 21</label>
    <input type="radio" name="22" class="checked">
    <label for="22">Answer 22</label>
    <input type="radio" name="23" class="">
    <label for="23">Answer 23</label>
    <input type="radio" name="24">
    <label for="24">Answer 24</label>
</fieldset>
```

Script:

```
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function (event) {
    // If the button is selected.
    if ($(this).hasClass("checked")) {
        // Remove the placeholder.
        $(this).removeClass("checked");
        // And remove the selection.
        $(this).removeAttr("checked");
        // If the button is not selected.
    } else {
        // Remove the placeholder from the other buttons.
        $("input[type='radio']").each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("checked");
        });
        // And add the placeholder to the button.
        $(this).addClass("checked");
    }
});
```

So if 21 is checked and I click 22, 21 should uncheck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the group of radios inside the same fieldset to act like a radio group then you can simply do

```
 $("input[type='radio']").click(function (event) {
     $(this).addClass("checked");    
     $(this).siblings('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false).removeClass('checked')
 });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hfb0o826/)

Comment: This works for the Fieldset as well. Initial pick for the correct answer didn't work with multiple fieldsets.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the value of the radio button to pass the id and give them all the same name.

```
<input type="radio" id="r21" value="21" name="radiobtns">
<label for="r21">21</label>
```

Then you don't need jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, all the radio button will unchecked except the clicked one. Like Aron P Johny said, if you want to group all the radio button with particular question and answer then go with his answer instead.

```js
$("input[type='radio']").click(function (event) {       
            $("input[type='radio']").prop('checked',false);
            $(this).prop('checked',true);      
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
    <input type="radio" name="21">
    <label for="21">Answer 21</label>
    <input type="radio" name="22" class="checked">
    <label for="22">Answer 22</label>
    <input type="radio" name="23" class="">
    <label for="23">Answer 23</label>
    <input type="radio" name="24">
    <label for="24">Answer 24</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Uh oh, looks like it deselects other questions in other fieldsets.  How can we get it to work for multiple fieldsets?

Answer (score 0):

`So if 21 is checked and I click 22, 21 should uncheck` if this is what you want you don't really need jQuery..

```
<fieldset>
 <input type="radio" name="radio_button">
 <label for="21">Answer 21</label>
 <input type="radio" name="radio_button" class="checked">
 <label for="22">Answer 22</label>
 <input type="radio" name="radio_button" class="">
 <label for="23">Answer 23</label>
 <input type="radio" name="radio_button">
 <label for="24">Answer 24</label>
</fieldset>
```

just make sure they all have the same name..

Comment: note that the use of radio button.. only 1 must be check and the other will be uncheck.. compared to checkbox you can check multiple of it.